# Difference between a Tunnel and a Socket ? And Advantages of one over the other

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming, tunnel

I am new to concept of tunnels, so facing a basic difficulty in understanding working of a socket and tunnel.

Making a tunnel returns a FD, but so does Socket.

I have read these two nice articles on Tunnel introduction :
[http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial](http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/)
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt

but unable to grasp this particular line about tunnels :
*instead of receiving packets from a physical 
media, receives them from user space program and instead of sending 
packets via physical media sends them to the user space program.*

Any frame or packet that I send from UserApp to kernel and outside the system, will go via physical media and reverse way back, using physical media. I might be missing an interpretation here.

So can anyone explain considering following parameter into the an example on How actually data goes on network and back to UserApp in a Socket & a Tunnel ?

FYI, I know Tunnel open a virtual device and Socket is a physical instance of the Ethernet/system.

Interaction between the following entities will help.

## System A:

Kernel - K1 , 
UserApp - U1 ,
Socket - S1 , 
Port - P1 , 
NIC - N1

## System B:

Kernel - K2 , 
UserApp -  U2 , 
Socket - S2 , 
Port - P2 , 
NIC - N2

Actually I am trying to architect a solution, where I might use multiple threads or I might have to use multiple sockets. Someone suggested it might take too much of user space and scheduling and asked to look into tunnels. So Here I am :)

thanks.